# Get count of missing links in MediaWiki?

Tags: php, mysql, wiki, mediawiki

How can I get the number of missing links that are in my Wiki? We have a lot of articles about all kinds of things that haven't been written or stubbed yet, but we want to provide a progress bar so the community can see how close we are to being more complete.

You can see the wiki here: http://worldeditor.org

If you have any tips related to that wiki, please do share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the source code that generates this page:
http://worldeditor.org/Special:WantedPages

And then change the select query to inlcude a count() statement.

Comment: Anyone know what source file generates this?

Comment: `includes/specials/SpecialWantedpages.php`

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if this is the information you're looking for, but:

At the left side of your MediaWiki page, under `Toolbox` you have `Special pages`; and on that page, a link to `Wanted`. That's a list of nonexistent pages pointed to in the Wiki.

Comment: Yeah I link to this directly in my MediaWiki skin under Contributors -> Wanted Pages